# Bootstrap dropdown static mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have set a dropdown menu to be static, so the content below is moved when the dropdown menu is expanded.

Currently the action on dropdown menu items, in this case alerts, registers on desktops but not on mobiles. 
So far I have tried with a Z1 compact and an iphone 6 and neither works.

**Fiddle here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2911/ (please try with mobile)

```
<div>ignore this</div>
```

I use alerts in Fiddle to show you what I mean, in the real projects I'm using normal href links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing dropdown-backdrop to static the problem went away.

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
    position: static !important;
}
```